# Adding non clustered index to temp tables for firing query quick in SSMS

Tags: sql, t-sql, temp-tables, non-clustered-index

So the current query I have takes 3 hours to run and realize i need to add non clustered index to run the query fast. So I have added this line of code but still its taking massive time with no result:

```
create nonclustered index #temp_index 
  on [dbo].#tempData ([class_room]) include ([class_name],[class_floor],[class_building])
```

This is the current query I have:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempdata') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempdata

    SELECT [class_room][class_name],[class_floor],[class_building]
    INTO #tempdata
    FROM class_info x

create nonclustered index #temp_index 
   on [dbo].#tempData ([class_room]) include ([class_name],[class_floor],[class_building])

;with cte1 as(
SELECT [class_room][class_name],[class_floor],[class_building]
FROM #tempdata
WHERE class_room <> '')  

select * from cte1
```

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan? Which part takes a long time? The insert into tempdata or the select?

Comment: For execution cost it shows:
Table Insert (#tempdata), Cost: 99%

Comment: Insert into temp table is taking long time as per execution plan. But when i just run upto that part it runs query fast

Comment: Am i using nonclustered index correctly?

Comment: Can you post the whole execution plan so we can see

Comment: I am not sure how to add the pic? Hang on..found it..!

Comment: Ok I tried adding image of plan, stackoverflow shows cancel and add another. Not sure why I am unable to add pic

Comment: How many rows are in class_info and why are you bothering with the temp table at all?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create `#tempdata` first.

```
create table #tempdata(
tempid int identity(1,1) not null, --to protect against duplicates
[class_room] varchar(50), 
[class_name] varchar(50),
[class_floor] varchar(50),
[class_building] varchar(50),
primary key (class_room, tempid), -- test this
unique (class_name,class_floor,class_building, tempid) -- or that
)
```

Comment: But its like creating a proper table.

Comment: Look at `#` sign before the name. It means temporary table. They are automatically dropped at the end of session. In all other respects they behave as usual tables.